# How to filter on nested aggregations

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to apply different filters for different nested aggregations. Is there a way to do this?

```
"filter": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "hierarchy.productGroup",
        "filter": {
            "terms": {
                "hierarchy.productGroup.name": ["iPhone"]
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "category": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "hierarchy.productGroup"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "category": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "hierarchy.productGroup.name"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "color": {
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "hierarchy.productGroup",
                "filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "hierarchy.productGroup.name": ["iPhone"]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "nested": {
            "path": "specs.measurementsProduct.colorName"
        },
        "aggs": {

            "color": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "specs.measurementsProduct.colorName.name"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this query I get the following error:

```
Error: Parse Failure [Found two aggregation type definitions in [color]: [filter] and [nested]]];
```

I would like to make my color aggregation dependent on the category filter.

Comment: It is hard to follow what you are trying to do - what do you want the results to look like?

Comment: I want to apply a filter on the color aggregation. If someone checks category "iPhone", I only want to return the colors that are available in that category.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a key **starting** and **ending**. 
Try with this json:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "hierarchy.productGroup",
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "hierarchy.productGroup.name": ["iPhone"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "category": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "hierarchy.productGroup"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "category": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "hierarchy.productGroup.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "hierarchy.productGroup",
                    "filter": {
                        "terms": {
                            "hierarchy.productGroup.name": ["iPhone"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "specs.measurementsProduct.colorName"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "color": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "specs.measurementsProduct.colorName.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```